# Applescript with do Javascript and passed Applescript Variable

Tags: javascript, variables, applescript

I have written a script that has automated the creation of products on a website I administer. In my process I upload JPEG images of the products and pull the Keywords that are tagged in the JPEG to add into the product information. In this process I use Applescript to Activate Safari and process a Javascript line of code. The line of code includes the a variable that is derived from Applescript Shell Script.

Code below

```
tell application "Finder"
set sourceFolder to folder POSIX file "/Users/<username>/Desktop/Upload/Temp/HighRes/"
set theFiles to files of sourceFolder
set inputPath to "/Users/<username>/Desktop/Upload/Temp/"

end tell

repeat with afile in theFiles

set filename to name of afile

set fname to text 1 thru ((offset of "." in filename) - 1) of filename

--INPUT CODE TO BE LOOPED OVER BELOW--


--Add Image Keywords from Metadata--
try
    set pathVAR1 to "/Users/<username>/Desktop/Upload/Temp/HighRes/"

    set pathVAR2 to pathVAR1 & filename

    set myvar to do shell script "mdls -name kMDItemKeywords " & quoted form of pathVAR2

    set var1 to ((offset of "(" in myvar) + 1)

    set var2 to ((length of myvar) - 1)

    set myKeywords to ((characters var1 thru var2 of myvar) as string)

    --Inputs the Keywords from the Image Metadata--
    tell application "Safari"
        activate
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('ctl00_cphMainContent_txtKeyWords').value = \"" & myKeywords & "\";" in current tab of window 1
    end tell
end try

--END OF CODE TO BE LOOPED OVER--


end repeat
```

==End Code==

Problem:

The code below is not passing the variable myKeywords to Safari, but if I run a dialog it will appear in the dialog.

```
do JavaScript "document.getElementById('ctl00_cphMainContent_txtKeyWords').value = \"" & myKeywords & "\";" in current tab of window 1
```

Comment: How do you know it's not passing the variable to _Safari_ ?

Comment: It’s not populating the box it should. If I put in a string word such as Hello World it places without issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tried the backticks ( ` ) suggested by CJK but that did not work for me. The main issue being raised was that the kMDItemKeywords returned escaped characters.

```
Heart,
Studio,
Red,
\"RF126-10.tif\",
Tree,
\"Heart Tree\",
occasion,
Farm,
birds,
\"Red Farm Studio\",
\"all occasion\",
all
```

I was able to get rid of the escaped characters using the following:

**NEW CODE**

```
set myKeywords to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of myKeywords & " | tr -d '[:cntrl:]'| tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr -d '\"'"
```

**UPDATED CODE FOR JAVASCRIPT**

```
--Inputs the Keywords from the Image Metadata--
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('ctl00_cphMainContent_txtKeyWords').value = '" & myKeywords & "';" in current tab of window 1
end tell
```

**RESULT**

```
--> "    heart,    studio,    red,    rf126-10.tif,    tree,    heart tree,    occasion,    farm,    birds,    red farm studio,    all occasion,    all"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a specific solution that will definitely solve your problem, but I do have a number of observations about your script with recommendations on how it can be changed to improve its speed, robustness and adherence to principles of best practice.

1. **Get rid of that `try` block.** You have no idea what's happening in your script when things go wrong if you're masking the errors with unnecessary error-catching. The only line that needs to be enclosed in `try...end try` is `do shell script`, but only put it in once you know your code is working.  In general, `try` blocks should only be used:

   - when your script has the potential to throw an error that is entirely ***predictable*** and ***explainable***, and you understand the reasons why and under what conditions the error occurs, allowing you to implement an effective error-handling method;
   - around the ***fewest possible*** number of lines of code within which the error arises, leaving all lines of code whose existence doesn't depend on the result of the error-prone statement(s);
   - after your script has been written, tested, and debugged, where placing the `try` block(s) no longer serves to force a script to continue executing in the wake of an inconvenient error of unknown origin, but has a clear and well-defined function to perform in harmony with your code, and not against it.
2. As a general rule in AppleScript, don't use *Finder* to perform file system operations if you can avoid it: it's slow, and blocks while it's performing the operations, meaning you can't interact with the GUI during this time.  Use *System Events* instead.  It's a faceless application that won't stop other things operating when it's performing a task; it's fast, in the context of AppleScript and *Finder* in particular, and isn't prone to timing out quite so much as *Finder* does; it handles posix paths natively (*including* expansion of tildes), without any coercion necessary using `POSIX file`; it returns `alias` objects, which are the universal class of file object that every other scriptable application understands.

   There are a couple of instances where *Finder* is still necessary.  *System Events* cannot `reveal` a file; nor can it get you the currently selected files in *Finder*.  But it's simple enough to have *Finder* retrieve the `selection` as an `alias list`, then switch to *System Events* to do the actual file handling on this list.
3. This is curious:

   ```
   set filename to name of afile
   set fname to text 1 thru ((offset of "." in filename) - 1) of filename
   ```

   Am I right in thinking that `fname` is intending to hold just the base file name portion of the file name, and this operation is designed to strip off the extension ?  It's a pretty good first attempt, and well done for using `text` here to itemise the components of the string rather than `characters`.  But, it would, of course, end up chopping off a lot more than just the file extension if the file name had more than one `"."` in it, which isn't uncommon.

   One way to safely castrate the end of the file name is to use `text item delimiters`:

   ```
   set filename to the name of afile
   set fname to the filename

   set my text item delimiters to "."
   if "." is in the filename then set fname to text items 1 thru -2 of the filename as text
   ```

   You should then be mindful or resetting the `text item delimiters` afterwards or there'll be consequences later on when you try and concatenate strings together.

   Another way of chopping of the extension without utilising `text item delimiters` is string scanning, which is where you iterate through the characters of a string performing operations or tests as you go, and achieving the desired outcome.  It's speedier than it sounds and a powerful technique for very complex string searching and manipulations:

   ```
   set filename to the name of afile
   set fname to the filename

   repeat while the last character of fname ≠ "."
       set fname to text 1 thru -2 of fname
   end

   set fname to text 1 thru -2 of fname
   ```

   You could also retrieve the `name extension` property of the file, get its length, and remove `(1 + that)` many characters from the end of the file's name.  There a myriad ways to achieve the same outcome.
4. This is wrong in this particular instance:

   ```
   set myKeywords to ((characters var1 thru var2 of myvar) as string)
   ```

   `characters` produces a `list`, which you then have to concatenate back into a `string`, and this is unsafe if you aren't sure what the `text item delimiters` are set to.  As you haven't made a reference to it in your script, it *should* be set to an empty string, which would result in the joining of the characters back into words produce the expected result.  However, this could easily not be the case, if, say, you performed the first technique of file extension castration and neglected to set the `text item limiters` back—then the resulting string would have a period between every single letter.

   As a policy in AppleScript (which you can personally choose to adhere to or ignore), it's considered by some as poor form if you perform list to string coercion operations *without* first setting the `text item delimiters` to a definitive value.

   But you needn't do so here, because rather than using `characters`, use `text`:

   ```
   set myKeywords to text var1 thru var2 of myvar
   ```
5. You're performing a shell command that looks like this: `mdls -name kMDItemKeywords <file>`, and then the two lines of AppleScript that follow awkwardly try and trim off the leading and trailing parentheses around the text representation of a bash array.  Instead, you can turn on the `-raw` flag for `mdls`, which simplifies the output by stripping off the name of the key for you.  This then places the parentheses as the very first and very last characters; however, since there's a load of dead whitespace in the output as well, you might as well get bash to perform all the clean up for you:

   ```sh
   mdls -raw -name kMDItemContentTypeTree <file> | grep -E -io '[^()",[:blank:]]+'
   ```

   This disregards parentheses, double quotes, commas, and whitespace, so all you get back is a list of keywords, one per line, and without any extra baggage.  If you needed to itemise them, you can set a variable to `the paragraphs of` the output from the `do shell script` command, which splits the text into lines placing each keyword into a list.  But it seems here that you need text and don't mind it being multilinear.

---

When I started to write this answer, I didn't have an inkling as to what was causing the specific issue that brought you here.  Having gone through the details of how `mdls` formats its output, I now see the issue is with the fact that the `myKeywords` string will contain a bunch of double quotes, and you've surrounded the placement of the `myKeywords` entity in your JavaScript expression with double quotes.  All of these quotes are only being escaped equally and once only in the AppleScript environment but not in the JavaScript environment, which results in each neighbouring double quote acting as an open-close pair.  I ran a similar command in bash to obtain an array of values (`kMDContentTreeType`), and then processed the text in the way AppleScript does, before opening the JavaScript console in my browser and pasting it to illustrate what's going on:

[image: JavaScript console]

Anything in red is contained inside a string; everything else is therefore taken as a JavaScript identifier or object (or it would be if the messed up quotes didn't also mess up the syntax, and then result in an unterminated string that's still expecting one last quote to pair with.

I think the solution is to use a continuation character `"\"` for backward compatibility with older browsers: so you would need to have each line (except the last one) appended with a backslash, ***and*** you need to change the pair of double quotes surrounding the `myKeywords`  value in your JavaScript expression to a pair of single quotes.  In newer browsers, you can forgo the headache of appending continuation marks to each line and instead replace the pair of outside double quotes with a pair of backticks (`` ` ``) instead:

```
❌'This line throws 
an EOF error in
JavaScript';


✅'This line is \
processed successfully \
in JavaScript';


✅`This line is also
processed successfully
in JavaScript`;
```

Comment: I believe that the kMDItemKeywords are not being processed correctly as they have escapes which could or are causing issues. I am just not sure how to correct this issues. That is the only part of the code that does not work. I have tested it with just a single work such as 
"

Comment: I believe that the kMDItemKeywords are not being processed correctly as they have escapes which could or are causing issues. I am just not sure how to correct this issues. That is the only part of the code that does not work. I have tested it with just a single work such as "TEST" and it does work. How do I correct this?

Comment: Did you read my answer ?  You haven't given any indication of whether the solutions I gave have been tried and worked or not ?  If you did try them, and they failed, please tell me in what way they failed, and what the output was.

Comment: While I understand that the rest of your code ***is*** functional, the aim of the first part of my contribution was to show you how to improve your code, in case you were interested.  It's fine if not, but just because a piece of code works, that doesn't mean it's good.  And good code is not only less prone to errors, but easier to fix if and when things do go wrong.

Comment: CJK - sorry for not providing a more detailed response. I did try your code in the modifications and it still did not return the values needed for input to Safari. Would you happen to have any additional ideas for how I can get the list without escape quotes? I truly appreciate all of your help and guidance

Comment: Which code are you referring to that you tried ?  You are aware that my answer did supply a way to get the list without any quotes, which then negates the need to do anything special with it ?

Comment: I made the modifications that you recommended above in numbers one through five, but in five it still did not result in the output needed. I tried five with both single and double quotes without outcome. In viewing the results in the AppleScript dialog I am seeing a number of the results have it escaped quotes and I believe that this is causing the issue of not transferring over properly to Safari

Comment: So therefore you didn't try the solution I gave at the end ?  The tips numbered 1-5 weren't intended to be a solution to the question—I stated this in the opening, but offered them to help improve the code.  Then, at the end, I realised what was likely causing the problem, and provided a solution.  Have you tried either adding the continuation character I mentioned, or using backticks in place of the double quotes ?

Comment: I did try the single quotes, but misunderstood the backtick. As per your suggestion, these should be added in place of the single or double quotes before and after the  myKeywords variable?

Comment: I didn't suggest to try single quotes.  Please read my answer again, _carefully_.  If there's a specific element that doesn't make sense, do ask.  But so far, I'm just repeating things I've already put in my answer, and it sounds like you haven't implemented either of the two key things that I hope will solve your problem.